# Scroll to new textfield when choosing a new textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios4

I have followed apple's guide [Managing keyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

It works like a charm unless you are already writing in a textfield and tab in a new textfield.

This is the function in the example that take cares of the scrolling. But it's never being called because it's already up?

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification;
```

Anyone know a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in .h

```
CGSize keyboardSize;
```

and

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification;
```

in .m

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    if (info) {
            /* Can get keyboard Size */
            keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]
    } 

    /* Animation code */

}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    activeField = textField;
    [self keyboardWasShown:[NSNotification notificationWithName:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil]];
}
```

Thanks to vakio.

Answer (score 1):

interface:

```
CGSize keyboardSize;
BOOL keyboardIsVisible;
```

implementation, keyboardWasShown:

```
keyboardSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
keyboardIsVisible = YES;
// Move ScrollView
```

keyboardWillBeHidden:

```
keyboardIsVisible = NO;
```

textFieldDidBeginEditing:

```
if (keyboardIsVisible) {
    // Move ScrollView
}
```

Comment: That's just common sense. As you can see in apples example it's already being listen on. So question is how can i execute the code that moves the keyboard from textFieldDidBeginEditing?

Comment: Well, you can simply call UIScrollView's `setContentOffset:` or `- (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated` and enter the textfield's rectangle. (And since you know the size of the keyboard from before when it was shown you can store that and use it in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, although you don't need to know the keyboard size here).

Comment: The key to keyboardWasShown function is that i can calculate what rectangle i want to be visable and where i want it to be visable by knowing the size of the keyboard.

Comment: See my edit for how to have keyboard size in `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`

Comment: I get your point, but textFieldDidBeginEditing: is called before keyboardWasShown, so first time i click i wont have it stored? Also i will execute same code functionality twice?

Comment: You can set keyboardSize to 0,0 when keyboard is not showing so you know when you have the size and when you don't, or you can have a boolean that is only on after `keyboardWasShown:`. Then you can do `if (keyboardIsVisible) { }`. You will have to set it to `NO` when the keyboard goes away.

Comment: I will still have the problem that `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is beeing called before `keyboardWasShown:` so i kinda need the animation in `keyboardWasShown:` and not just setting a variable with the size.

Comment: Yes, you will have to move the scrollview in both places. Store the keyboard size, then move in keyboardWasShown:.

Comment: I could actually call `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` manually from `keyboardWasShown:`. Gonna try it out

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. You will make your code more prone to bugs. Better is to create another method that moves the UIScrollView and is called from both methods based on CGRects.

Comment: I found a sweet solution, thanks to you. If you update your post with it i can accept it as answer. Check my post for the solution. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: No problem, but I can't put your code as my answer; it's your answer (albeit very similar to mine). If you don't think my answer is correct then you don't have to accept if you don't want. You can put your code as an answer and accept your own answer. I'm glad I could help at least.